# Powershell store data in variable as text when called by start-job

Tags: powershell, jobs

I have a script that generate a logfile at startup, write things in it, and done.
It works well on main script, but the variable gets evaluated again when passed to subscripts using start-job.

Here is how I define this variable :

```
$logFile = (Get-Location|Select -expand Path)+"\"+(Get-Date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")+".log"
```

Here is how I write data to log in the main script :

```
"here is some log data" | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
```

Here is how I start a job :

```
$job=Start-Job -Name "myjob" -FilePath ".\worker.ps1" -ArgumentList
$logFile
```

The problem is when I write data to the log inside my worker.ps1 subscript, the $logfile value is evaluated again, then I end up having multiple different log files instead of one : because $logFile seems to be evaluated again when called with start-job.

My worker looks like this :

```
Param (

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$logFile
)

"This is a test" | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
```

I end up having 
2017-02-20-13-55-23.log
2017-02-20-13-56-20.log
2017-02-20-13-57-14.log
...

I believe this is not how it should work, $logFile variable should not get evaluated again, but with jobs I'm getting some funny experiences and I'd like to get some help on this one.

Thanks for ideas

Comment: Have you considered using an environment variable, or creating a variable using `Set-Variable` and specifying a broader scope? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable

Comment: Good idea ! I tried "Set-Variable -Name "logFile" -Value ((Get-Location|Select -expand Path)+"\"+(Get-Date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")+"=.log") -Option constant -Scope global" but I have the same problem :(

Comment: It's sometime hard to get something easy with powershell. I think my problem could be summarized like this : "how to store text generated from cmdlets inside a variable and not the generating code". I need a $logFile = (some-cmdlet).toStringAndNotAnotherExtremelyAnnoyingPowershellObject

Comment: Hmm, I don't think the problem is what you think it is. A string is a string, it doesn't recalculate, and what you have is a string. Check for where you define $logfile and make sure it's not in any loops or anything, and also make sure you aren't re-defining it in your subscripts.

Comment: Try environment variable instead. Global won't be shared with the job.

Comment: you are right, I was passing the $logfile as an parameter but also sourcing the file defining it... I'm dumb :) thanks for help guys. Can't find where to give points (if I can)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are facing this issue, I will recommend you to put this line inside your ***worker.ps1***. This should help you out:

```
Param (

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$logFile
)
Remove-Variable logFile -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
"This is a test" | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
```

This will remove the variable each time before so that a new instance of $logfile will get initiated.

Hope it helps.